# How to have a perfect snapshot of a website using Python Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am in the process of creating an application that given a website URL, will download it, including its dependent CSS/JS/Images resources. It'll also create an offline working version of the web. I heavily depend on Beautiful Soup to parse the html response text, iterate all of its external resources (css/js/images/etc) and download it locally. It's sometimes working beautifully. Sometimes don't

My study case is [this website](http://www.hall.com). I have this glitches in the offline --supposedly-- working version of the web:
[image: glitches]

The footer got displayed first. Surely many factor can cause this trouble. But, judging from Chrome inspector that don't complain about any missing resources, I am not sure what the problem is.

Although, after I inspect the HTML written by Soup using this code:

```
with open(os.path.join(save_to_dir, name + '_(Offline)' + '.html'), 'w') as fd:
            fd.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
```

.., I realize that the HTML is overly modified. For example, below is the live version of the web:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>HALL | Group Chat, Instant Messaging</title>
<meta name="description"
      content="Hall is group chat and IM for companies and teams. Available free for the web, desktop and mobile. FREE anytime, anywhere.">
<meta property="og:title" content="Hall"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Real-time chat &amp; texting for business teams."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://d3bkj0l4dzdp7x.cloudfront.net/static-assets/hall_logo_400x200.jpg"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

While the Soup version is shown below:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
<title>HALL | Group Chat, Instant Messaging</title>
<meta content="Hall is group chat and IM for companies and teams. Available free for the web, desktop and mobile. FREE anytime, anywhere." name="description">
<meta content="Hall" property="og:title"/>
<meta content="Real-time chat &amp; texting for business teams." property="og:description"/>
<meta content="https://d3bkj0l4dzdp7x.cloudfront.net/static-assets/hall_logo_400x200.jpg" property="og:image"/>
<meta content="chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

The above is just an example.
But, my question is, how to achieve --with Soup-- a HTML result that closely mimic its live/input version?

Comment: I cant see a difference between the HTML, except the attribute order. Can you point out where the difference is?

Comment: Pardon that I kinda mislead you here :) The above snippet is just an example that bsoup not creating a perfect snapshot of the web: which I think it has the possibility to create a non working offline version of the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atributes of a tag in beautifulsoup are held by a dictionary. And since a dictionary doesn't use indexes, the attributes can be shuffled. With other words it isn't possible to do this with bsoup.

A solution would be:

1. Get the website.
2. Save it in a file.
3. Use beautifulsoup to get the sources and stuff.

With this you will have an exact copy of your response as your file and it is still possible to use bsoup  without any slow downs.

Comment: Correct! After posting this question, I also come up with the idea of combining the use of bsoup+local file download. I just have to somehow change the offline version to refer to this local download. I will accept your answer for this!

Answer (score 1):

Just a little bit more detailed than Vincent's answer

1. To get the website, if you hava access to Linux, you can use

`wget --random-wait --no-check-certificate -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla https://hall.com/`

to "download" the whole website.

2. Use BeautifulSoup to process the local files

You can even write a simple shell script and run it everyday to save a snapshot of a website.

Just a reminder, DO NOT CRAWL A WEBSITE FREQUENTLY!

Comment: Nice! Although I think another step needed, e.g, `3. Copy web downloaded from #1, and change all external references to locally downloaded resources rom #2`. Sorta ... :)